# SetAlarmClock() on Xiaomi

Tags: alarmmanager, android-alarms, xiaomi, setalarmclock

A proven example of using Set Alarm Clock(), which will work on Xiaomi mobile devices.

I tested on my Redmi X5, the alarm only goes off when the app is open and not minimized. The alarm icon in notification area does not appear. The permissions are present in the manifest. Everything works as it should on the emulator.